# HTML scroll box in theme doesn't fit/ too wide when viewed in mobile browser*

Tags: html, css, mobile

I just completed my website using WordPress 'Theron'Lite' theme.

I have added a customized scroll box into my pages. The theme looks great on my PC, however, on my mobile device, the scroll box is too wide and runs off the page, so the user has to move the page over to the right (basically has to scroll "out of the website") to read all of the information in the scroll box.

I tried fixing several of the 'widths' coding to "100%", but with no success. I certainly don't mind posting the HTML from my .css, I'm just not sure if the problem resides in my style.css or mobile.css. Or even the scroll box HTML that I placed into my individual pages is the culprit. Either way, something's screwed up here.

Any ideas? I greatly appreciate any help in this matter!

Answer (score 0):

When using the 100% width you might try adding !important after wards to allow that to overwrite any other css that potentially could be affecting the scroll box.

Something like this:

```
.scrollbox
{
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Otherwise, could you at least post a URL to the site?

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will try that!

Here's the URL to my site: http://paradigmcurve.com/?page_id=2

...It seems to look fine on my laptop/ PC, but not on my mobile browser :)

I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out. I haven't quite mastered the talent of this stuff yet.

Comment: Ok, it's definitely not the scrollbar causing the information to scroll "outside of the page", because even after removing the scrollbox entirely, the problem persists. So it must be a .css problem of some sort with the theme. I'm stumped though, ha.

Comment: Some progress here-- It's not exactly the way I want it (still too wide), but I may be onto something... I placed this into my .css... 

@media only screen and (min-width:40%) and (max-width:90%) {
.container {
position:relative;
}

Comment: @user3155202 For some reason my PC would not load your site. I think it's due to firewall restrictions at my location. However, if you could post the relevant CSS and HTML that would be a help.